# Excel Macro to be run till the values are there

Tags: excel, vba

I recorded a Macro for the below excel:-

[image]

Macro Code:-

```
Sub Macro4()
'
' Macro4 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+D
'
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "P"
    Range("B1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C$13").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Credit"
    Range("B3").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=-RC[-1]"
    Range("B3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A3").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Range("B12").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("B11").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C$13").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Debit"
    Range("B2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]"
    Range("B2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Range("B13").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("B2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Columns("A:B").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00_ ;[Red]-#,##0.00 "
    Range("B1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
End Sub
```

This gives the result:-

[image]

When I try the same Macro on the below excel:-

[image]

This gives the below result.

[image]

In reality, I don't know how many prices be there so how can edit my Macro in such a way that it selects all the range till the last row

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a formule for this?

```
B2=IFERROR(IF(C2="credit",A2*(-1),(IF(C2="Debit"),A2,""),""),"")
```

Then just use conditional formatting on the column to get the colors.
If you insist on a macro, you can add find last row and loop through all rows to check the value of column C.
Should be easy to find and copy from google, there are a lot of simular examples.

Double check the formula, I’ve written it om my sellphone but it should be ok

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code. It takes a different approach.

```
Sub BookToLedger()

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim R As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")       ' change tab name to suit
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        .Columns(2).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        .Cells(1, 2).Value = "Amount"
    End With

    With Rng
        .NumberFormat = "#,##0.00_ ;[Red]-#,##0.00 "
        .Copy Destination:=.Offset(0, 1)
        Set Rng = .Offset(0, 1)
    End With

    For Each Cell In Rng.Cells
        With Cell
            If Left(.Offset(0, 1).Value, 2) = "Cr" Then
                .Value = .Value * -1
            End If
        End With
    Next Cell
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The code first sets the number format in column A. Then it inserts a copy of column A, including the new number format, in a new column B. Finally it loops through all entries in column B and makes the credit values negative.

Answer (score 0):

This macro will run in activesheet. So select the sheet before you run this macro. or add first line to mention the sheet.

```
Sub Macro4()
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+D
Range("A1").Select
Dim tblRng As Range, cl As Range

Columns("B:B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = "P"

Set tblRng = Range("A2", Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

For Each cl In Range(tblRng.Cells(1, 2), tblRng.Cells(tblRng.Rows.Count, 2))
If cl.Offset(0, 1) = "Credit" Then cl = -cl.Offset(0, -1)
If cl.Offset(0, 1) = "Debit" Then cl = cl.Offset(0, -1)
Next

Range(tblRng.Cells(1, 1), tblRng.Cells(tblRng.Rows.Count, 2)).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00_ ;[Red]-#,##0.00 "


End Sub
```